# Setting up .xib, views, controllers, etc. for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, interface-builder

I'm trying to integrate a UIWebView in my app following a tutorial. I believe I've written up the code correctly, but I'm having a little problem with the instructions from the tutorial:

> We start by adding a new view to the
>   project. Drag and drop an UIWebView
>   control on the view. As always, create
>   an controller to handle the view, I
>   have named the view and the view
>   controller “WebView” and
>   “WebViewController” respectively. We
>   create a new object of type UIWebView
>   and also declare an associated
>   property. We will use this object to
>   connect “WebView” view placed on the
>   view.

My MainWindow.xib looks like this:

[image]

And I have a ViewController called iPhoneTestAppViewController that looks like this:

[image]

My question is this: **Step by step, what do I need to do in Interface Builder to set up a UIWebView?**. Like I said, I believe my code is good (pretty much exactly the same as in the tutorial). I'm just lacking in the Interface Builder skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is, to quote the tutorial, "Drag and drop an UIWebView control on the view. "  In other words, add a peer to LevelMeter etc, and then size it to fit appropriately on the screen.  Then just control-drag from your webView object you just added to the File Owner object (which I assume you've previously assigned the type of "iPhoneTestAppViewController").  This will add a webview to your view, which should operate according to the tutorial, but...

I confess that I'm concerned that you expect all those Level-meter, buttons, and textFields to be a part of your webView, which is not the way things work.  It will be on the same screen as those things, but operating essentially independently.  Sorry if I'm not understanding your goal for the webview.

Comment: Okay, this is getting really close. Although to clarify (and to address your second paragraph) I _don't_ want all of the buttons, etc. apart of my webview. What I'm looking to do is to have the WebView appear _on top_ (visually, not necessarily programmatically) over the view of buttons etc. Any idea how that should be properly done?

Comment: Well, if you simply layer them in IBuilder (Arrangement menu), then the "top" one will receive the touches, but the others will be visible through, depending on the opaque status of the upper ones. Is that what you mean? If you want it to appear above, but NOT get the touches, I believe that's what turning off the option "User Interaction Enabled" will provide.

Comment: Actually it is even simpler then that. Speaking from the UI point of view (not the coders) I would like all of the buttons, etc. in one main 'view'. Then when the UIWebview appears I would like it so ALL you seen is the Webpage. Nothing else. As if it switching views, so to speak. Right now I'm trying to do this by having a different view controller which pops up a view when the user hits a button. But then I need to somehow pass the url from the iPhoneTestAppViewController to the new viewer. Well, I hope this doesn't make things more confusing.

Comment: Well, having it push a separate view controller (via a navController or modalVC) would be fine (just set a property for the URL, before pushing it).  But if all you want is to put the WebView up, you can just set it at the top, but with its visibility off in IB, and then turn it on when you want it.

Comment: Oh, and then there's the question of how (or if) the user gets out of the web view